# How to use Entity Framework Core in XAF

Tags: entity-framework-core, xaf

Is it possible to use Entity Framework Core 1 (formerly Entity Framework 7) in XAF (eXpress Application Framework)?

Comment: Correction: EF is supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAF 22.2.3 supports EFCore 6.0.3
Note when upgrading old projects the primary keys in the security system have changed to GUIDS.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

> Does XAF support Microsoft’s Entity Framework?
>
> Yes. XAF provides support for Entity Framework. You can use your existing EF data models in order to generate an XAF application. Please review the Business Model Design page to learn more.

From https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Application_Framework/presales-faq.xml

**UPDATE**
To clarify, it is possible to use EF Core because XAF runs on .NET. If what you are asking is "does XAF work out-of-box with EF Core?" the answer is no. XAF's baked-in class EFObjectSpace is for EF6 and older because it relies on the ObjectContext API. EF Core does not support the ObjectContext API.

Comment: I don't mean EF, I mean EF Core or EF 7.0 which is totally different that EF 6

Comment: As long as XAF runs on .NET 4.5.1 or greater, EF Core should work fine.

Comment: Currently there is no ObjectSpaceProvider that supports EF7.

Comment: Is it possible to use EF Core vs does it fit XAF's interfaces are separate questions. Is it possible? Yes. Does XAF provide an ObjectSpaceProvider for EF Core? Probably not. But you can still use EF Core on any XAF because under the hood XAF runs on .NET.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, DevExpress [Cross-Platform .NET App UI (XAF)](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/application_framework/) and its backend [Web API Service](https://www.devexpress.com/products/net/application_framework/security-web-api-service.xml) provide a "first-class citizen" support for Microsoft Entity Framework Core (EF Core). Supported versions include:

- EF Core 7 in XAF v23.1+
- EF Core 6 in XAF v22.2+
- EF Core 5 in XAF v20.2-v22.1
- EF Core 3 in XAF v20.1-v20.2

DevExpress also [recommends EF Core over XPO ORM for new XAF development](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/404186/why-we-recommend-ef-core-over-xpo) and new XAF projects target EF Core by default.

For more information, follow [Business Model Design with Entity Framework Core](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/401886/business-model-design-orm/business-model-design-with-entity-framework-core) and [Getting Started](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/113577/getting-started).

Comment: Thank you. When is it going to publish as an official ORM for XAF, so we can use it in production?

Comment: I cannot give you the exact ETA at this stage. I suggest you watch our GitHub repository or [XAF Team blog](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/xaf/default.aspx) for any updates.

Comment: We have released XAF's Security System for EF Core 3 in v20.1.6. You may find these overview videos helpful to get started: https://youtu.be/sIhWOXRWlOw and https://youtu.be/o1q4GqFgSFE

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do the migration by creating a new .net core5 project from the wizard and then moving my classes into the new project.
Unfortunately The .Net5 security tables are different to those that the framework project uses so I wont be able to do a staged roll out.